# Returned list is redundant after recursion

Tags: list, recursion, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and I have a problem when appending a list to an existing list.

(Funcion spec) The following function takes 2 args; an atom and a list. The list takes 2-dimensional form where each sub-list looks like `(index counter)` (both index and counter are atoms). If `target` is equal to one of the `index`es, `counter` increments. If no sub-list contains `target`, add a new sub-list with `counter` = 1.

```
(defun contained (target list)
  (cond ((null list) (list target 1))
    ((= (car (car list)) target)
     (setf (cadr (car list))
           (+ (cadr (car list)) 1)))
    (t (push (contained target (cdr list)) list))))
```

The problem is when `target` doesn't exist yet. As shown below, lists and parentheses get redundant.

```
> la
((1 4) (2 1))
> (contained 3 la)
(((3 1) (2 1)) (1 4) (2 1))
```

What I want is something like:

```
((3 1) (1 4) (2 1))
```

Sorry not to have been able to simplify the problem, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun contained (target list)
  (cond
    ((null list) (list target 1)) ; you are returning a new element of target

    ((= (car (car list)) target)
     (setf (cadr (car list))
           (+ (cadr (car list)) 1))) ; you are returning... what?

    ;; yet you are pushing on every recursive call!
    (t (push (contained target (cdr list)) list))))
```

At the risk of doing your homework for you, here's one way to do it (with help from Miron Brezuleanu):

```
(defun contained (target list)
    (let ((elm (assoc target list)))
        (if elm 
            (progn (incf (cadr elm)) list)
            (cons (list target 1) list))))
```

Here's a way to do it closer to your original

```
(defun contained (target list)
  (cond
    ((null list) (list (list target 1)))
    ((= (car (car list)) target)
     (setf (cadr (car list))
           (+ (cadr (car list)) 1))
     list)
    (t (setf (cdr list) (contained target (cdr list)))
       list)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I particularly appreciate the one that's closer to my original, since I haven't found the definition of `elm` so far online.

Comment: In this specific case "elm" seems to be short for "element" (similar to elt, I guess).

Comment: `elm` is a variable that is bound by the let form. However, that particular version of contained looks weird to me: on one branch of the `if` it returns an integer, on the other a list. Not sure how I could use such a function :-) Maybe what the author meant was `(defun contained (target list)
    (let ((elm (assoc target list)))
        (if elm 
            (progn
              (incf (cadr elm))
              list)
            (cons (cons target 1) list))))`? (use of `assoc` also assumes that the elements of the list are not lists, but conses).

Comment: The version using `elm` does not return any useful value; this is a design decision and an instructional point. Since the function modifies the list argument, there is no need to return anything (and the "specification" did not require the function to return any particular value).

Comment: @Doug Currie - if the `elm` version doesn't return anything useful, why does it cons? You're modifying the list argument on only one branch, you seem to assume the user will use the returned value on the other branch - or your `cons` is smarter than mine :-)

Comment: @MironBrezuleanu, you are absolutely correct; a few minutes after writing my comment I realized it; that you for being persistent. I'll modify my answer accordingly.